# Is there any convenient way to convert w3c Document to jsoup one

Tags: java, html, javafx, jsoup, w3c

Basically I have javafx' `WebEngine` and I want to parse contents of current webpage using Jsoup instead of built-in w3c. But `webEngine.getDocument()` returns w3c's `Document` and I can't find any good way to convert it to Jsoup's one. The only way I can think about right now is converting original `Document` to String and then parsing it with Jsoup, which is quite clumsy

Comment: Me as well, best I could find was Jsoup.parse(new W3CDom().asString(webEngine.getDocument()));

Answer (score 1):

That's the way I do it and it works nicely.

```
WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
String html = (String) webEngine.executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
```

I then pass the string "html" to JSoup.

Comment: The question especially says "The only way I can think about right now is converting original Document to String and then parsing it with Jsoup, which is quite clumsy". What you suggest to do may be correct, but it doesn't answer the question.